Issues with Rendering Transparent Glass in <model-viewer> using .glb File
I am working on a web project where I need to render a 3D model of a mocktail with a transparent glass and additional elements like lemon slices and ice cubes. The model was created in Blender and exported as a .glb file. The transparent glass looks perfect in Blender, but when rendered using the <model-viewer> component, the glass appears white and lacks proper transparency.
Here are the details of my setup:
Export Settings:
File -> Export -> glTF 2.0
Include: Selected Objects
Apply Modifiers: Checked
Materials: Export
Format: glTF Embedded
Model-Viewer Code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script
      type="module"
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/model-viewer/3.5.0/model-viewer.min.js"
    ></script>
</head>
<body>

<model-viewer
          src="models/Mocktail.glb"
          ar
          ar-modes="webxr scene-viewer quick-look"
          touch-action="pan-y"
          camera-controls
          tone-mapping="neutral"
          poster="poster.webp"
          shadow-intensity="1" >
          <div class="progress-bar hide" slot="progress-bar">
            <div class="update-bar"></div>
          </div>
          <button slot="ar-button" id="ar-button">
            View in your space
          </button>
</model-viewer>

</body>
</html>

Output in website)
Actual model from blender 
Observed Issue:
The transparent glass renders as white and does not show proper transparency as it does in Blender.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Verified the export settings in Blender.
Tested different <model-viewer> attributes such as environment-image, exposure, and shadow-intensity.
Confirmed browser compatibility with WebGL 2.0.
Tested rendering with different browsers.
Despite these efforts, the issue persists. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve the same transparency effect in <model-viewer> as seen in Blender. Is there something specific I might be missing in the viewer configuration?
Thank you for your assistance!
